# If Statement is being bypassed in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am new to .Net. This might be a silly question, but, please bear with me. I don't know what got wrong but 'if' statement in the server script is being bypassed. i used web forms.  could you please tell me a solution?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">

protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int price = 0;
    int fee = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCourses.SelectedItem.Value);
    price += fee;

    if (rbMorning.Checked || rbAfternoon.Checked)
        price -= fee * (10 / 100);

    if (cbMaterial.Checked)
        price += fee * (10 / 100);

    lblMsg.Text = "Total Fee: " + price;


}
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>CoursesApp 1.0</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h3>Courses Application</h3>

        <br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCourses" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="3000">Java SE</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4500">Java EE</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="6000">.Net</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3000">Oracle DB</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbMorning" runat="server" Text="Morning" Checked="True" GroupName="timing" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbAfternoon" runat="server" Text="Afternoon" GroupName="timing" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbEvening" runat="server" Text="Evening" GroupName="timing" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbMaterial" runat="server" Text="Material" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCalculate" runat="server" OnClick="btnCalculate_Click" Text="Calculate" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>

    </div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put a break point and check if `rbMorning.Checked` and `rbAfternoon.Checked` has value or not.

Comment: @madan which one of the given If statement is getting bypassed ?

Comment: which `if`? there are two `if`s in your code. moreover, if you think it is skipping, then what does it show for `lblMsg.Text`? what is your use-case?

Comment: Both of them are being bypassed.

Comment: Ankush Madankar: I checked. its returning the value.

Comment: Maybe its not being bypassed - its just that it doesn't met the condition. Check the values.

Comment: @madan compiler implicitly takes your 10 and 100 as Int type you can check it while debugging what is the type. So any numbers whose remainder is non-zero will be rounded to nearest integer in your case it will be zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem :** your expression always yeilds `0` when divide you do `(10/100)` and when multiply zero with fee it would be again zero, hence there is no subtraction or addition will take place.

**Solution :** you need to `multiply` the `fee` with `10` and then `divide` it by `100`.

Try This:

```
    if (rbMorning.Checked || rbAfternoon.Checked)
        price -= (10 * fee / 100);

    if (cbMaterial.Checked)
        price += (10 * fee / 100);
```

Comment: what is the change you have made here??

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi +!1 Good catch

Answer (score 3):

One thing i would like to add however Sudhakar already had given the answer that `(10/100)` yields `0` because compiler implicitly takes your `10` and `100` as `Int` type you can check it while debugging what is the type.
So any numbers whose remainder is non-zero will be rounded to nearest integer in your case it will be zero.

You can do as sudhakar answer or a workaround will be to let compiler know you want those two figures in `double`  type by defining `10` as `10.0` and 100 as 100.0

```
if (rbMorning.Checked || rbAfternoon.Checked)
    price -= fee * (10.0 / 100.0);

if (cbMaterial.Checked)
    price += fee * (10.0 / 100.0);
```

Comment: @Suraj Singh: yea its a nice one too. Thank you.